# 301 Rewriting htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I have list of url's to redirect using htaccess.
from my OLD domain to New domain.

i have done this in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

redirection working fine, But i want something like `http://sub.domain1.com/old-page` to `http://www.domain2.com/my-new-page`

and i did this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain1.com/old-page/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/my-new-page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and the url is `http://www.domain2.com/old-page/`

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^old-page/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/my-new-page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works on my test.